# Releasing CountDownLatch only when I receive a callback in one of my Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

When to invoke `doneSignal.await()` in this scenario??
My requirement is to wait the return call until callback is received.
I tried invoking it in other thread and also in main thread. But no luck, callback is never received thereby freezing the app and initially when I was not using the CountDownLatch getCall was returning null value immediately without waiting for the callback. Below is my code

```
public UserSubscriptions getDocument(final String uid) {
        final UserSubscriptions[] userSubscriptions = new UserSubscriptions[1];
        final CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
        try {
            Thread getCall = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 try{
                    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("xyz").document(uid);
                    docRef.get()
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    userSubscriptions[0] = null;
                                    TimerLog.e("document retrieve failed");
                                    doneSignal.countDown();
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                                    userSubscriptions[0] = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserSubscriptions.class);
                                    TimerLog.e("document retrieved successfully " + userSubscriptions[0].toString());
                                    doneSignal.countDown();
                                }
                            });
                    TimerLog.e("control exitted from run");
                } finally {
                        TimerLog.e("Nads in finally");
                    }
                }
            });
            getCall.start();
            TimerLog.e("before");
            doneSignal.await();
            TimerLog.e("after");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            TimerLog.e("exception in await "+e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return userSubscriptions[0];
    }
```

Console Output :

```
before
control exitted from run
in finally
```

Comment: You shouldn't need both join and await. My guess is that the thread terminates without triggering either the success or failure callback. Perhaps there is an exception (you don't catch runtime exceptions)? Add a try/finally block in the run method and log when it exits. You could also catch Exception or Throwable in order to log the error (if any) for debugging.

Comment: @ewramner  I was using `join()` before using latch. Now tried removing it and also wrote the content of run method inside `try` block but no exceptions occurring still app is freezing. Once the control reaches `await` then it not even receives the callback thats the cause of freezing.

Comment: But does control exit from the run method (i.e. log in your finally block)? I think that registering success and failure listeners won't block, so the run method just returns and neither callback is called. Then the application will hang.

Comment: @ewramner yes control exits from run. Have updated the code along with the console logs.My only concern is I'm not receiving callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CountDownLatch did not work for me neither any mutual exclusive lock thing. The best way to do such type of thing where you are receiving a callback from server then you should not have that function return anything. Simple method is to have callback functionality.